# llvm-rs-cc is missing flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am new in flutter. I got Llvm-rs-cc is missing when trying to run the flutter project after installing the sdk but flutter doctor not detect any issue. I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and android studio project (kotlin) run without any issue. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't seen such an issue mentioned. Consider creating a big report with the output of `flutter doctor -v` and all other information that you think could be relevant.

Comment: the same issue. Please write if you'll fix it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem,Here's how I solved

1. Navigate to Home/User/Android/Sdk/build-tools.
2. Delete all the folders from there.
3. Go to SDK Manager and download the latest version of Android SDK build-tools.

Note:You can find Android SDK build-tools in second tab of SDK Manager.